# ion-input type text should only accept alphabets + ionic2

Tags: forms, ionic-framework, ionic2

ion-input type text should only accept alphabets without using the form Builder.

```
        <ion-item class="myitem">

            <ion-input type="text" value="" placeholder="Full Name*" [(ngModel)]="fullname" maxlength="25"></ion-input>

        </ion-item >
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with **html** adding the `pattern` attribute to your input.

Alphabets and blankspace:

```
pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"
```

Alphabets no blankspace:

```
pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
```

Alternate

```
[pattern]="'^[a-zA-Z \-\']$'"
```

Comment: @Faizan Fazi upvote or accept as answer if it helps.thanks

Comment: @FaizanFazi please check updated code.and tell me if any error occurs

Answer (score 0):

alternately you can use,

```
<ion-input class=" " (keypress)="onKeyPress($event)"> </ion-input>
```

and

```
onKeyPress(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) || (event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122) || event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 46) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

it will work for me

Comment: keycode is not available in android keyboard api... so can't solve with this.